# Error loading textures using Spritekit and Texture Packer

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, texturepacker

I am using `SpriteKit` and `Texture` Packer. I have a small sequence of animation. I was able to load certain images such as background and logos. But when I try to load the `texture`, which has an animation sequence using -

```
SKSpriteNode *char1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:TEST_TEX_CHARACTER01];
```

It says `SKTexture:Error loading image resource: "character01".`

Please help me out!

Comment: missing file extension perhaps? Shouldn't it be character01.png?

Comment: Maybe not directly related to your question, however you don't need to use Texture Packer when you use SpriteKit. SpriteKit has a neat way of creating texture atlases automatically. Here's a pretty good documentation on how to create animations with SpriteKit using texture atlases (http://www.raywenderlich.com/45152/sprite-kit-tutorial-animations-and-texture-atlases).

If you want the actual problem solved you should probably provide more code + details about asset names, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Texture Packer creates a header file when you tell it you are using SpriteKit. I came across the same issue recently, although it worked just fine in a previous game. Everything *appears* to be correct in the plist, header and atlas.

I will edit my answer with a solution when I find one.

EDIT:

This turned out to be pretty simple. If you have any images with @2x in the name, change the name to a plain file name (e.g. ship@2x.png needs to be ship.png).

With that change to any files that need it and re-publishing your atlas from Texture Packer you should be able to use the convenience macro name from the header, e.g.

```
SKSpriteNode *ship = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:ARTWORK_TEX_SHIP];
```